# How does Zend Framework 2 render partials inside a module?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got something like this for my directory structure inside a module:

```
Api
├── Module.php
├── config
│   └── module.config.php
├── src
│   └── ( ..etc ..)
└── view
    ├── api
    │   └── api
    │       └── index.phtml
    └── partial
            └── test.phtml
```

Then, I'm doing this:

```
<?= $this->partial('partial/test.pthml', array()); ?>
```

However, I get:

> 05-Jun-2012 14:56:58] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message
>   'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template
>   "partial/test.pthml"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in
>   /Users/jeff/web/n/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:463

Where *should* my partials go?

Comment: Your directory structure is correct and your partial view helper is set correctly. Just make sure you have `'template_path_stack' => array('user' => __DIR__ . '/../view')` added to your `module.config.php` file and you should be good.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this can be achieved by

```
 echo $this->partial('layout/header', array('vr' => 'zf2'));
```

you can access the variable in view using

```
echo $this->vr;
```

don't forget to add following line in your view_manager of module.config.php file.

```
'layout/header'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
```

after adding it looks like this

```
return array(  

'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view' ,
        ),
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',

            'layout/header'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',            

            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),


    ),    

);
```

Comment: In my module, I use the following: $this->partial('{module}/{controller}/{filename}.phtml',array('var_name_in_partial' => $data));

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to include the name of your module in the called to the View Helper partial()?

http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial.modules

```
<?php echo $this->partial('pager.phtml', 'list', $pagerData) ?>
```