# Zend Framework 2 display a view within a view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have two modules Admin and Login.

I want to display the Login view 'login.phtml' within the admin view 'index.html'

I have the following in the Admin modules indexAction controller

```
public function indexAction()
{    
    $login = new LoginController();

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'theloginform' => $login->loginAction(),
    ));

    return $view;
}
```

In the LoginAction method in the Login controller I return the ViewModel for the 'login.phtml' file.

```
public function LoginAction() {
       $view = new ViewModel();
       return $view;
}
```

The indexAction throws an error as the variable 'theloginform' is an object.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\View\Model\ViewModel could not be converted to string in...
```

If i add the following:

```
$authentication->loginAction()->captureTo('test')
```

The 'index.phtml' shows a string "content".

I have read that i may need to render the ViewModel before i assign it to the view variable 'theloginform', but i can't seem to get it to work, i have tried the following with no luck.

```
public function LoginAction() {

    $view = new ViewModel();

    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
    $map = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
            'login'      => __DIR__ . '/../view/login.phtml'

    ));
    $resolver->attach($map);
    $view->setTemplate("login");
    return $renderer->render($view);
}
```

If get the following error:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "login"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

I have even tried adding the DI into the autoload_classmap.php file but still get the same error, i have double checked the login.phtml file is at the correct path:

'/Login/view/login/login/login.phtml' I even copied it to '/Login/src/Login/view/login.phtml'

Very confused have read then re-read the Zend documentation, i just want to pass a view to another view...

Comment: Why you want to call another view? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In the Admin Module i have 'index.phtml' that i want to add the Login Module 'login.phtml' to. The Login Module 'login.phtml' view will also be added other views in other modules such as a Customer Account module.

Comment: I'm too lazy for an answer right before lunchbreak, but check around Rob Allens playground > https://github.com/akrabat/ZF2TestApp/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/ViewController.php It will help you a lot. you may also be interested in the following question > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451399/how-to-render-zf2-view-within-json-response/12651250#12651250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZF 1.x I would likely recommend you build an action helper that is referenced to a view placeholder or a controller plugin that calls back to loginAction for the form logic.

In Zf2 it looks like action helpers have been replaced by [controller plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) and seem to be triggered through the [event manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) and may need to be aware of one or more of the ["managers"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html). However the [placeholder view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#placeholder-helper) still exists and even seems somewhat familiar.

I would suggest you look into building/adapting a controller plugin for your login form display that can then be attached to a placeholder view helper. You might be able to get the required functionality with just a view helper, if you're lucky.

I wish I could help more, but I'm still wading through this mess myself.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers i am currently building a controller plugin, tried a partial helper but it will not work with a form object. Currently battling with the zend framework myself, stuck on httpRequest objects specifically how to get the current request, might be opening up another ticket :)

Comment: Just read about the serviceManager in regards to httpRequest....complete misunderstanding of the framework what a beast the Zend framework is!

Answer (score 4):

If you need share some view content you can use partials for that:

```
$this->partial('partial/login.pthml', array()); //add this to your index view
```

you can read about them [here](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html)

You may also find some usefull information: [How does Zend Framework 2 render partials inside a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903451/how-does-zend-framework-2-render-partials-inside-a-module)

Comment: Thanks for that, how would you use the 'Login/view/login/login/login.phtml' file as a partial view inside the 'Admin/view/admin/admin/index.phtml'?  Do you have to register the login.phtml file as a partial helper somewhere?

Comment: You are designing your application wrong, the view files meant to be called by specific controller:action in most cases. If You see that you have some parts of your website that you want reuse, create partial for that. Like in this case it could be login form. Which then can submit to some controller action, and then on controller you decide what to do with results, redirect somwhere or display some results.

Answer (score 4):

As per [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#nesting-view-models) zf2 documentaion page

Write this in login Action:

```
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

And in indexAction :

```
    $view = new ViewModel(
                  array(
                    //here any thig you want to assign to index view
                  )
                );
    $loginView = new ViewModel(
                  array(
                        //here any thig you want to assign to login view
                    )
                );


    $loginView->setTemplate('moduleName/controllerName/login'); 

    $view->addChild($loginView, 'login');
    return $view
```

In index.phtml you can just echo login `<? echo $this->login ?>` where ever you want to display loginView.

Comment: What if I have something like this in the controller: " $viewModel->addChild($formViewModel,  $studEvalId);" ? How can I echo the child viewModel in the .phtml file without knowing the captureTo used for addChild() in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

In you admin view you have to use the render view helper and echo the script rendered, so you can do  `echo $this->render($this->theloginform);`